# Single socks5-authorization and making many requests using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socks

I have some access to socks5 server (host, port, username and password). I need to be authorized and then make several requests to different servers by TCP via this socks5 proxy. How I can make it with node.js?

I found library [socks-client](https://github.com/JoshGlazebrook/socks-client) and it is ok, but I have to be authorized for each request to remote server (by using method 'connect'). How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the nature of the SOCKS protocol. You connect, authenticate, and then if successful normal data is transferred back and forth on the same connection. There is no way to re-use a connection, so you have to repeat the process for every new connection you want to make.

Comment: As I understood socks5 has 'associate' type of connection. It allows to send data to different hosts but only by UDP. Is it impossible to do same things by TCP?

Comment: No. There is no multiplexing provided by the SOCKS protocol. UDP works easily because it's connectionless so there's no real multiplexing needed.